# Angular two-way binding doesn't work with data input

Tags: angular

I am trying to do an easy thing but it doesn't work. 
Could you please help me to print the date value into the data field ?
Please consider that I don't want to change the property `datetask` to a string

you can test it here in case
https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-in-actions?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftask%2Ftask.component.ts

thanks

```
//CLASS
export class Task {
      id: Number;                 
      description: String;    
      datetask: Date;  
}


//COMPONENT
item :Task
constructor() {
      var obj = new Task();      
      obj.datetask =  new Date();
      this.item = obj;
}


<!-- VIEW -->
<form [formGroup]="form" autocomplete="off">             
      data: <input  [(ngModel)]="item.datetask" id="datetask" [formControl]="datetask" type="date">               
      <button    type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: date inputs don't accept the js Data object. this link should help you out https://blog.johanneshoppe.de/2016/10/angular-2-how-to-use-date-input-controls-with-angular-forms/

Comment: what calendar field?

Comment: @jacopo <input type="date">

Comment: @L.A  install another component just for read a date value ?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly : `print the date value into the data field`?

Comment: yes, just print the date value  into the data field leaving the datetask property to date

Comment: @Gelso77 that is the cleanest way i have seen. the date input format is yyyy-mm-dd (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) to you could also format your date to that format on input and reformat it to date on output but thats rather ugly

Comment: @L.A  if I convert the data object to a string it works...but I am really surpirce that I can't send a Data object to a input data field

Answer (score 0):

Did you install these in your app.module.ts file?

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';

...

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
...
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Yes i did.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-in-actions?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Sorry, I missed the link to stackblitz.  I figured you had it.